# Cramer-Wold device for merging measures

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

For each $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$ 
introduce a linear functional $l_a$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $l_a(x)=\langle x,a \rangle$. 
It is a known fact that if $P_n,P$ are probability measures and $\rho(P_nl_a^{-1},Pl_a^{-1})\to 0$ for each $a$, then $\rho(P_n,P)\to 0$ when $n \to +\infty$. Here $\rho$ is the Levy-Prokhorov metric. This is, in fact, the Cramer-Wold device.

Now suppose that we have two sequences $(P_n),(Q_n)$ of probability measures. Suppose that $\rho(P_nl_a^{-1},Q_nl_a^{-1})\to 0$ for each $a$. Does it imply $\rho(P_n,Q_n)\to 0$?

And what if $\underset{|a|\leq 1}{sup}\rho(P_nl_a^{-1},Q_nl_a^{-1})\to 0$? Does this stronger condition imply $\rho(P_n,Q_n)\to 0$?